# Compare Items In A List Of Nested Dicts And Perform Simple Arithmetic Operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How can I put the list "image_list" into a function measure_accuracy then have it return a number of times actual and predicted are the same? In this case, it would return 3.

List:

```
image_list = [
  { 'path':'1.jpg', 'actual':{'dog'}, 'predicted':{'dog'} },
  { 'path':'2.jpg', 'actual':{'dog'}, 'predicted':{'cat'} },
  { 'path':'3.jpg', 'actual':{'cat'}, 'predicted':{'cat'} },
  { 'path':'4.jpg', 'actual':{'cat'}, 'predicted':{'dog'} },
  { 'path':'5.jpg', 'actual':{'dog'}, 'predicted':{'dog'} }
]
```

So what I want is to compare each item in the list and if then if the two items are the same add to a variable then in the end return that variable.
I just do not know the code to get there.

I thought maybe something like

```
for actual, predicted in image_list:
    if actual == predicted:
        count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [7]: sum(x['actual'] == x['predicted'] for x in image_list)
Out[7]: 3
```

so:

```
def measure_accuracy(image_list):
    return sum(x['actual'] == x['predicted'] for x in image_list)

total = measure_accuracy(image_list)
average = total / len(image_list)
```

A brief explanation of what's happening here:

```
x['actual'] == x['predicted']
```

Evaluates to either `True` or `False`. In Python, `True == 1` and `False == 0`, so we're getting 1 each time the predicted value is equal to the actual value, otherwise 0. So our list would look like this:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

then we use the `sum` function to add them all together to get 3.

Comment: Just a note to anyone who doesn't know: This works because booleans in Python are subclasses of integers. This means you can use the normal list of integer operators on booleans as well. `True`'s integer value is `1` and `False`'s is `0`. eg: `True + True == 2`, `False + True == 1`.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I was editing my post with more clarity.

Comment: How do I divide 3 by the amount of items in list. So in this case 5?

Comment: add `/ len(image_list)`. I've updated my original answer to show you what I mean beneat h the `measure_accuracy` function.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!